# Why aren't my todo items rendering with Redux?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I'm doing a simple redux / react todo app. I can't get the todo items to show up. I'm able to `console.log` the data, but can't get it to appear. What am I doing wrong?

I separated the files, here is my `app.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Todos from './todos';
import TodoList from "./todo_list";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Todos />
        <TodoList/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the container `Todos`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { addTodo } from '../actions/index';

class Todos extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {text: ''};
    }

    addTodo(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addTodo(this.state.text);
        this.setState({
            text: ''
        });
    }

    updateValue(e) {
        this.setState({text: e.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={(e) => this.addTodo(e)}>
                    <input
                        placeholder="Add Todo"
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            this.updateValue(e)
                        }}
                    />
                    <button type="submit">Add Todo</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({addTodo}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Todos);
```

Here is the `TodoList`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class TodoList extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                { this.props.todo.map((tod) => {
                    return <li key={tod.message}>{ tod.message }</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps({ todo }) {
    console.log({ todo });
    return { todo };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TodoList);
```

Reducer:

```
import { ADD_TODO } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state=[], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return [ action.payload.message, ...state ]
    }
    return state;
}
```

And action

```
import { ADD_TODO } from './types';
const uid = () => Math.random().toString(34).slice(2);

export function addTodo(message) {
    const action = {
        id: uid(),
        message: message
    };
    return {
        type: ADD_TODO,
        payload: action
    };
}
```

This is what I get from the console.log({todo});

[image]

Here is my reducers/index:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import TodosReducer from './reducer_addTodo';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    todo: TodosReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: what do you get from console.log({todo}) ?

Comment: I added an edit on the question, that shows what I get from the console.log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because there's a disconnect between your `TodoList` and reducer. `TodoList`, when mapping, expects each todo to have a `message` prop, but your reducer, when returning next state, only includes the message in the state array, not an object with the `message` property:

```
case ADD_TODO:
  return [ action.payload.message, ...state ]
```

Instead, do not just put the `message` string in the next state's array, put in the whole object:

```
case ADD_TODO:
  return [ action.payload, ...state ]
```

Now every single element in the `todo` array will be an object and have a `message` and `id` property. Also, try using an always unique expression for `key` -- it really shouldn't be the todo message, nor the `id` you supplied because it's using `Math.random` which both have a possibility of keys being the same.